# Fine Uploader -- Upload failed

Tags: fine-uploader

I would like to upload a file using Fine Uploader. I used the example given at the website:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Fine Uploader Demo</title>
    <link href="fineuploader-3.5.0.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="fine-uploader"></div>
    <script src="fineuploader-3.5.0.js"></script>
    <script>
       function createUploader() {
          var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
             element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader'),
             request: {endpoint: 'test.php'}
          });
       }
       window.onload = createUploader;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Apparently the upload process was fine. However, when the uploading finished, I got the "Upload failed" message.

I think we need another server-side script to handle the upload. How can the server-side script 'test.php' accept the upload? Any sample code provided will be appreciated.

Also, for Fine Uploader, is there an upper limit to the size of the file being uploaded? I tried uploading a 5GB file and it didn't seem to work.

Lastly, how can we display the rate of upload as well as the time remaining?

Comment: There is a comprehensive php example in the server side repo: https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/tree/master/php

Answer (score 3):

@Deonia is right, and I would like to add a comment, but apparently don't have enough reputation...

---

There is a fairly comprehensive PHP example on the [server-side repository](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/tree/master/php).

You'll notice that the [handleUpload](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/blob/master/php/qqFileUploader.php#L42) function returns an associative array. This is the response from the server that indicates success. Check out [the docs on server-side responses](http://docs.fineuploader.com/integrating/server/#response) for ideas on what's valid.

In essence, anything other than a `{ success: true }` response will result in Fine Uploader thinking the upload failed.

Comment: Here's the new link for the docs you referred to: https://docs.fineuploader.com/endpoint_handlers/traditional.html#response

Answer (score 1):

You have asked so many questions

Firstly ,you need to use jquery for progress bar you want to show. A very nice tutorial to make such is [here](http://www.ultramegatech.com/2010/10/create-an-upload-progress-bar-with-php-and-jquery/)  . So I am not writing code here .

The upload of file bigger than 5GB is handeled by your script allowance and its server timeout time. You need to check and allow the file upload timeout more than 1 hour depends on you .

**NEW update**

As you asked the question the below is the answer

```
request: {
            // path to server-side upload script
        endpoint: 'test.php'
         }
```

Also in your `test.php` file uncomment:

```
 // max file size in bytes (Below I have made 10GB)

    $sizeLimit = 10 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
```

Comment: What do we use for the 'endpoint'? Do we type the name of a PHP file?

Comment: @ChongLipPhang I have answered the question above . If you staisfy please accept the answer and vote up then :)