# Fine Uploader — Upload failed in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, fine-uploader

[This problem occur in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828631/fine-uploader-upload-failed) While uploading with fine-uploader, uploaded fine.but when finish uploading, it give me upload failed. But file is uploaded. My script is below.

```
<script>
(function() {
    $('#fine-uploader-gallery').fineUploader({
        template: 'qq-template-gallery',
        request: {
            endpoint: '/admin/files/upload',
            params: {
                authenticity_token: "<%= form_authenticity_token %>"
            }
        },
        failedUploadTextDisplay: {
            mode: 'custom'
        },
        callbacks: {
            onComplete: function (id, fileName, responseJSON) {
                alert('done' + responseJSON.success);
                // give alert "donefalse"
                if (responseJSON.success){
                    alert('Ok uploaded fine')
                }
            }
        },
        thumbnails: {
            placeholders: {
                waitingPath: '/images/fine_uploader/waiting-generic.png',
                notAvailablePath: '/images/fine_uploader/not_available-generic.png'
            }
        }
    });

}).call(this);
```

How can I fix it ? 
Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix above my error, link below. Add my controller below .

```
render json: {success: true}
```

Then for fine uploader script add chunking

```
 chunking: {
   enabled: true
}
```

Then fix it.